# clojure behavior of (into {} '((:a :b) (:c :d)))

Tags: clojure

```
user=> (into {} '((:a :b) (:c :d)))
```

Throws: `ClassCastException clojure.lang.Keyword cannot be cast to java.util.Map$Entry  clojure.lang.ATransientMap.conj (ATransientMap.java:44)`.

Whereas:

```
user=> (into {} (list [:a :b] [:c :d]))
```

Is fine. It's a strange difference, since many times other functions return lists when the thing they had to begin with was a vector:

```
user=> (into {} (partition 2 (interleave [:a :b] [:c :d])))
```

Will throw, because it `partition 2 ...)` results in `((:a :c) (:b :d))`. So it's pretty annoying. You basically have to memorize both the return types of methods and the specific behaviors of functions like `into`, or you have to just let stuff blow up and fix it as you find it with stuff like `(into {} (map vec (partition 2 (interleave [:a :b] [:c :d]))))`.

Is there a specific reason why `into` doesn't like the pairs as lists?

Comment: `into` is probably built on top of `conj`. `(conj {} '(:a :b))` =>
 `java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.Keyword cannot be cast to java.util.Map$Entry` Which changes the question to why does `conj` only take a vector pair when conjing onto a map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is as you state, only a vector pairs can be used to build maps. I don't know of a practical reason why this limitation exists. But there are also several other methods for constructing hash-maps. If you find yourself using partition, perhaps the answer is to use an alternate construction method.

If you have parallel sequences of keys and values:

```
(zipmap [:a :c] [:b :d])
```

If you have all the items in a flat sequence:

```
(apply hash-map [:a :b :c :d])
```

Building a map from a sequence:

```
(into {} (for [[k v] xs]
           [k (transform v)]))
```

Comment: yeah not sure why I didn't think of `(apply hash-map ...)`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I never realized this wouldn't work!  Don't forget:

```
(apply hash-map (interleave [:a :b] [:c :d]))
;=> {:b :d, :a :c}
```

since `hash-map` implicitly creates pairs from the scalar args:

```
(hash-map :a :c :b :d)
 ;=> {:b :d, :a :c}
```

you don't really need the `(partition 2...)` which is the source of the problem.